# The solutions of differential equations for a fractional order of differentiation that is a function of x

Tags: functional-analysis, fractional-calculus

The fractional derivative of $x^k$, for $k>0$, is

$$\frac{d^a}{dx^a}x^k = \frac{\Gamma{(k+1)}}{\Gamma{(k-a+1)}}x^{k-a}$$

Variabilising the order of differentiation by making it a function of $x$, we can write equations of which each solution, if any solutions exist, send one function to another by differentiating it, giving

$$\frac{d ^{u(x)}}{dx^{u(x)}} f(x) = g(x)$$

An example of a specific case is

$$\frac{d ^{u(x)}}{dx^{u(x)}} x^2 = x.$$

Putting $k=2$ into the definition of the fractional derivative, we get

$$\frac{d^a}{dx^a}x^2 = \frac{\Gamma{(3)}}{\Gamma{(3-a)}}x^{2-a}=\frac{2x^{2-a}}{\Gamma{(3-a)}}.$$

Writing $a$ as $u(x)$, putting the expression as equal to $x$, and assuming the denominator is non-zero, we get:

$$2x^{1-u(x)}=\Gamma{(3-u(x))}.$$

Writing $3-u(x)$ as $v$, we get

$$2x^{v-2}=\Gamma(v).$$

When $x=1$, one solution is $u=3$ and another is $u=0.443$;
when $x=2$, we get $u=1$ and $u=4.46$;
when $x=2.1$, $u=1.04$ and $u=4.64$.

What can we say about $u(x)$? What can we say more generally about $u(x)$, for example if rather than sending $x^2$ to $x$, we send $\sin(x)$ to $x$?

Comment: Although this nice problem is motivated by fractional calculus, the functional equation itself has nothing left to relate it to fractional derivatives.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but it suggests a nice notation, as in, say, $[x^2,x]=u(x)$, with which we can ask questions such as "*what is y(x) if $[y(x), \sin{x}]=e^x$*?" and "*what space of functions is generated by $[f(x),g(x)]$ where f, g are polynomials*?"

Comment: Note that exponentials and the gamma function have an infinite amount of branches, mainly when defined for $x\in\mathbb C$